# Angular filter observables with criteria

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

in an angular 5 project, I want to filter observables with a criteria. The criteria should tell the filter in which column he must filter.

The param data contains the term and the criteria from the search formular.

I don't know where to add the criteria param.

My actual code:

```
public search(data: any): any {
  console.log(data.criteria);
  return Observable.from(ELEMENT_DATA)
    .filter(element => element.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(data.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()))
    .map(element => element.name)
    .subscribe(
      element => console.log(element),
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('Streaming is over')
    );
}
```

Thanks for your help :-)

Best Regards

Comment: You can do just `filter(element => element[data.criteria].toLocaleLowerCase()...`

Comment: It works! Thanks :-)